# Suppressing PHP Errors & Warnings Using @ Not working with set_error_handler

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to connect to TCP Server, When the server is working i should get true and when it is, I supposed to get false.

But that what I'm getting instead of false:

```
    Error: [2], fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /website/classes/Main.php on line 2874
```

My code:

```
public function checkInternetConnection(){

        $connected = @fsockopen("www.gossssogle.com", 80);

        if (!$connected){
          return false;
        }else{
            fclose($connected);
            return true;
        }
        return $is_conn;

}
```

The problem I guess that I'm using set_error_handler so @ before function name isn't working

```
set_error_handler('customError');
```

Error Handler function

```
    function  customError($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext){
    $error_number = rand(1111 , 99999999);
    $message = "Error Number:" . $error_number . "\r\n";
    $message .= date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\r\n";
    $message .= "Error: [" . $errno ."], " . "$errstr in $errfile on line $errline \r\n, ";
    $message .= "Variables:" . print_r($errcontext, true) . "\r\n";



    error_log($message, 3, log_file);

   throw new internalError();
}
```

**Q:**
How can I check if the connection status instead of getting PHP error?

Comment: `@` does not really suppress errors. It just resets the error_level *temporarily*. You'll have to adapt your error handler to recognize that.

Comment: @mario it was just a try, I've tried to ignore these types of error in my error handler, its working and not reporting any error as supposed but it's not returning false in case there's no connection. it's throwing 'internalError()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did, is ignoring throwing an exception in case there is some error with sockets.

```
function  customError($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext){
    $error_number = rand(1111 , 99999999);
    $message = "Error Number:" . $error_number . "\r\n";
    $message .= date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\r\n";
    $message .= "Error: [" . $errno ."], " . "$errstr in $errfile on line $errline \r\n, ";
    $message .= "Variables:" . print_r($errcontext, true) . "\r\n";

    if (!stristr($message, 'stream_socket_client')) 
    error_log($message, 3, log_file);
    else return false;

   throw new internalError();
}
```

it's working, but I guess there should be a better solution.